# Hibernate Components as composite identifiers

Tags: hibernate, postgresql, hibernate-mapping, composite-component, composite-key

I have following 3 tables in postgres ...

`table Address { address_id, address_line1, country, zip, owner_id, owner_type }`

`table Employee { employee_id, first_name, last_name }`

`table Company { company_id, description }`

And following are my domain classes ...

`class Address { addressLine1, country, zip }`

`class Employee { id, firstName, lastName, List<Address>}`

`class Company { id, description, List<Address> }`

Employee and Company has one-to-many relationship with Address.

If it is Employee address, owner_id = employee_id and owner_type = 'Employee'

If it is Company address, owner_id = company_id and owner_type = 'Company'

How can I achieve this relationship with hibernate using xml configuration? My domain classes are inside a common jar, so I don't have liberty to directly touch them.